# How to update XML nodes with new values?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xmldocument, xmlnode

I have a xml inside my `App_Data` folder. I need to edit the values in nodes of that xml. What I had tried is-

```
        XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xDoc.Load(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/conf.xml.config"));

        XmlNodeList aNodes = xDoc.SelectNodes("/ConfigInf");
        foreach (XmlNode node in aNodes)
        {
            XmlNode child1 = node.SelectSingleNode("Node1");
            XmlNode child2 = node.SelectSingleNode("Node2");              

            child1.InnerText = "Value1";
            child2.InnerText = "Value2";
        }
```

I need to re-write the xml with new values as when ever I try to access the same xml again, it should contain the new values. But when I access the xml, I still get the old(initial) values only when I call like this -`Test.LoadConf(Server.MapPath("./App_Data/conf.xml.config"));`. How to write to XML with new values or any alternative method like create a new xml with new values?(as I need to access this xml in a single page only)

Comment: You probably want to save the file after making these changes as they have only been applied in memory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

call save after edit, you can give diferent name if you don't need to overwrite the original

e.g.  new file named as `new.conf.xml.config`

```
xDoc.Save(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/new.conf.xml.config"));
```

next time you can load the original as usual

```
xDoc.Load(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/conf.xml.config"));
```

Comment: Damith, Thanx a lot for your answer. But its take some time as Visual studio displaying a message box saying the file has been modified outside of the source... Any way to avoid this?

Comment: because you added this configuration file to your solution. when that file update by the application VS warn you that file modified outside.. When you actually deploy this app there is no issue. don't worry about this

Comment: No issues as I saved to new xml file. Thanks for your valuable inputs.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't saved the file after that

use `xDoc.save(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/conf.xml.config"));`

Answer (score 0):

The nodeValue property can be used to change the value of a text node.

The following code changes the text node value of the first element: Example:

```
xmlDoc=loadXMLDoc("books.xml");

x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0];
x.nodeValue="Easy Cooking";
```

source: http://www.w3schools.com/DOM/dom_nodes_set.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
node["Node1"].InnerText = "Value1";
node["Node2"].InnerText = "Value2";
```