# how to persist text data in winforms app?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on a winforms app using C# and wanted to add a save feature to a few parts where the user would be bale to enter text into a textbox and have it saved for next time.

how is this implemented in winforms?
I am trying a local xml file and failing to persists the text while being able to read it. data.xml is the local file in my project root folder.

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(@"(full path)\visual studio 2015\Projects\My_helper\data.xml");

string subject = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode(@"./content/reminder_email/subject").InnerText.ToString();

string body = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode(@"./content/reminder_email/body").InnerText.ToString();
```

Comment: If there are only few things to be saved I would suggest you to use [Property Settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650555/how-to-use-settings-in-visual-c-sharp)

Comment: What should be structure of your xml and under which node you want to save data? Did take a look at [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9616163/c-sharp-modify-a-xml-node) or [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16806838/how-to-update-xml-nodes-with-new-values) ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# : Modify a xml node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9616163/c-sharp-modify-a-xml-node)

Answer (score 1):

Using settings is probably the easiest approach.

Read: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869(v=vs.80).aspx

- Create a setting in the solution explorer as a string type
- Assign using Properties.Settings.Default.*Your Setting Name* = TextBox1.Text
- Read using TextBox1.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.*Your Setting Name*

Don't forget to call Properties.Settings.Default.Save(); after changing a setting.

Comment: will these persist between reboots and close/ open of the app ?

Comment: Yes using settings retains the data between runs.

Answer (score 0):

The XML approach is a good one, I've used it a lot.  But beware where you choose to store it.  For instance, if your application is installed to `ProgramFiles`, you won't be able to write there.  You'd have to store it in `ProgramData`, or in the user's space.

As for the application settings, it's not really a bad way to go, but it's also not meant to be data storage.  So if it's really data you're storing, use something meant for that purpose:  a database or at least XML.